# how to add a column in Pandas derived from another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to sum worked hs (Time Spent) and then group them but I am stucked in the first step (convert the column and extract the values)

Here is an example:

```py
df = pd.read_excel("Time spent week.xls")

df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 18 entries, 0 to 17
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column             Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------             --------------  -----         
 0   Task title         18 non-null     object        
 1   User               18 non-null     object        
 2   Date               18 non-null     datetime64[ns]
 3   Time spent         18 non-null     object        
 4   Project or folder  18 non-null     object        
 5   Category           15 non-null     object        
 6   DateYW             18 non-null     object        
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), object(6)
memory usage: 1.1+ KB
```

The format of the information on Time Spent is like this --> 01:00:00

I tried this and I cant understand the problem

```py
def strip2(val):
    new_val = val.split(sep=':', maxsplit=1)
    return float(new_val)
df["Time spent2"] = df["Time spent"].apply(strip2)
```

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-4f94c4e06b06> in <module>
      2     new_val = val.split(sep=':', maxsplit=1)
      3     return float(new_val)
----> 4 df["Time spent2"] = df["Time spent"].apply(strip2)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4136             else:
   4137                 values = self.astype(object)._values
-> 4138                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4139 
   4140         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-65-4f94c4e06b06> in strip2(val)
      1 def strip2(val):
----> 2     new_val = val.split(sep=':', maxsplit=1)
      3     return float(new_val)
      4 df["Time spent2"] = df["Time spent"].apply(strip2)

AttributeError: 'datetime.time' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: It is a `datetime.time` object. Convert to string first if you really want to split. Alternatively format with [strftime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html)

Comment: Convert to string first  `df["Time spent2"] = df["Time spent"].astype(str).apply(strip2)`

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-163-26afedfda162> in <module>
----> 1 df["Time spent2"] = df["Time spent"].astype(str).apply(strip2)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4136             else:
   4137                 values = self.astype(object)._values
-> 4138                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4139

Comment: 4140         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-65-4f94c4e06b06> in strip2(val)
      1 def strip2(val):
      2     new_val = val.split(sep=':', maxsplit=1)
----> 3     return float(new_val)
      4 df["Time spent2"] = df["Time spent"].apply(strip2)

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

Answer (score 0):

Use the to_datetime function, specifying a format to match your data.

```
df['Time spent'] =  df.to_datetime(df['Time spent'], format='%H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Hi ! Thank you. Unfortunately it doesnt worked.

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-156-ed3dc22f0912> in <module>
----> 1 df['Time spent'] =  df.to_datetime(df['Time spent'], format='%H:%M:%S')

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)

Comment: 5463             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5464                 return self[name]
-> 5465             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5466 
   5467     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'